# How do I insert my search bar in the header menu next to the logo. Please show me what i did wrong?

Tags: css, html

Hello i am new to this site and new to programming in general. I am currently trying to put together this site (just practice) but i seem to be stuck i cannot move the search bar up next to the logo. I know my menu items are also incorrect and i will retry them after i can solve this search bar problem. 
I currently have to files open an index.html and a style.css

Here is the html.index page below.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FindFriends</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="headerMenu">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                        <img src="./img/find_friends_logo.png"/>
                    </div>
                    </div class="search_box" />
                                <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                                    <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search."/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="menu">
                            <a href="#" />Home</a>
                            <a href="#" />About</a>
                            <a href="#" />Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="60%" valign="top">
                        <h2>Join Find Friends Today</h2>
                    </td>
                    <td width="%" valign="top">
                        <h2>Sign Up Below</h2>  
                        <form action="#" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="username" size="25" placeholder="Username" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="email2" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Email" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="password" size="25" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="password2" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Password" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" >
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

And here is the style.css page below.

---

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #eff5f9;
}
.headerMenu {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: auto;
        padding-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 1000px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.logo {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        width: 125px;
}
.logo img {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 38px;
        padding-top: 5px;


}

        .search-box {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        margin-left: 135px;

}



    #search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../img/search_dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #267bb6;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 9px 15px 9px 35px;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }
    #search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(../img/search_light.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu {
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-top: 19px;
    margin-right: 2%;

}
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  #menu {
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
  #menu {
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 4%;

}
}
 #menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: name;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover {

    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg_hover_mouse_over.png);

}
h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #0084c6;
}
input[type="text"] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #006fc4;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #006FC4;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

---

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: First i noticed this one `</div class="search_box" />`. How it will work??

Comment: first correct your html too many wrong placed tags.

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply could you please show me how i would need to correct these tags? apologies in advance i have no local help yet i am wanting to learn.

Comment: I see now  Suresh Ponnukalai  it should be </div class="search-box"/> am i right?

Comment: No, it should be `<div class="search_box">`.

Comment: Thank you ralph i appreciate all the help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Check your class names in html and css after that you should use css `float:left;` properties in your logo div and search-box div

Comment: Thank you so much ahakanergun!!  that fixed the search bar problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your html, I hope I didn't missed something.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FindFriends</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>


    <body>

        <div class="headerMenu">

            <div id="wrapper">


                <div class="logo">
                        <img src="./img/find_friends_logo.png"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="search_box">
                                <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                                    <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search." />
                                </form>
                    </div>
                            <div id="menu">
                            <a href="#" >Home</a>
                            <a href="#" >About</a>
                            <a href="#" >Sign Up</a>

                            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

            <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="60%" valign="top">
                        <h2>Join Find Friends Today</h2>
                    </td>
                    <td width="40%" valign="top">
                        <h2>Sign Up Below</h2>  
                        <form action="#" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="username" size="25" placeholder="Username" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="email2" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Email" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="password" size="25" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="text" name="password2" size="25" placeholder="Confirm Password" /><br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" >
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For css, there are a lot of mistakes there too.but I will answer your question:

```
.logo {
        width: 150px;
        float:left;
}
.search-box {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        margin-left: 135px;
          float:left;

}
```

I recomend to rewrite the css, because it have a lot of mistakes.Some things to keep in mind:
1.Why do you have for logo 3 logo images?one from html, and 2 as background images?(only one image is needed).
2.You can't use position absolute without position relative on the containing div.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
.a{position:relative}
.b{position:absolute}
```

This is how you should use potition.[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) you have some documentation for position.Hope that helped you a bit

Comment: i ended up restarting the whole project so it is a little different now but thank alot for your time to help me i appreciate it.